# Differentiate full name without spaces

Tags: javascript, java

If i have Full name coming as an input from the user without any spaces, how would i be able to differentiate first name and last name. The Full name for the input could be any name (generic input).

Comment: isn't that should be in your problem statement/domain ? How would someone guess.

Comment: is the fullname written whit some works in uppercase?

Comment: How is that related to either JavaScript or Java? Also why did you tag two completely different languages?

Comment: The answer to your question (language agnostic, btw) is that you can't. Also worth reading: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: This is insane. Programming languages are not super human. You cant build a logic to handle general case if there where some criteria like starts with upper or lower cases such things..then we can handle. In general you can not.

Comment: Isn't there any kind of inbuilt dictionary, that can be used for a pattern matching ?

Comment: Dictionary of EVERY SINGLE HUMAN NAME? No, there isn't. Considering it'd be outdated immediately after it's created, it'd be rather useless.

Comment: *"inbuilt dictionary"* - into what? You tagged two completely unrelated languages. Also no, because there is **NO** solution to this problem (What about people with only 1 name? Or people with 2 or more? What about ordering? Charactersets?)

Answer (score 3):

**In the general case, you can't.**

There are some things you **might** be able to do depending on what you receive. For instance, if you get `"JohnSmith"`, then you can probably split them on the first uppercase character that isn't the first character of the string, but that could break in all kinds of ways —`"ManueldelaVega"`, for instance, or `"JOHNSMITH"` or `"mohammedibnabdul"`.

So again: In the general case, you can't.

Comment: why can't it be a comment ? This will encourage more answers like this, which I don't think should be.

Comment: @Mritunjay: It's an answer to the question asked. So I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Well I feel this is totally a comment and this question should be closed as `too broad` or `primarily opinion based`.

Comment: @Mritunjay: You're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: So, I can differentiate full name by this finding the capital letter coming afterwards the first capital letter and there is no solution for input with all capital letters or all small letters.

Comment: @RakeshJain What if the user puts their last name first? e.g.: `NakamuraHikaru`?

Comment: @RakeshJain: And even if you've been given capital letters, it will fail for a lot of names, which is what the `"ManueldelaVega"` was meant to point out. If someone's name is "Manuel de la Vega", in a firstname/lastname system (which is not sufficiently flexible to handle the world's names), normally the first name would be "Manuel" and the last name would be "de la Vega".